# get device token from all phone from api server in ionic

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification

I've added push notification to my ionic mobile app using this tutorial : https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/ and it's working fine.

The problem now is, to send notifications you need a device token from the phone (this is obtained after registering the device) and the server api is going to use it to send the notification. But I can't have it manually from all the phone I'm testing. How is it theoritically done for distribution to send the notification to all the phone that installed the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would usually store the device-token in a database on the backend-side once you receive it. When you want to send a notification to all devices, you fetch all the tokens from the database and send a message to each one.

Comment: So basically if I understand, I might have an api-like in my app that always push the device token to my DB ? And then the web app will just fetch that and send the notification ?